# Best way to wait until a variable changes its value

Tags: codenameone

I realize that what I'm about to ask is more a generic Java question than a specific Codename One question, anyway, considering that the reference APIs are Codename One's, is there a more elegant and more reliable way to handle a situation like the following code? Such cases happen if I need to synchronously make code that by its nature would be asynchronous with callback:

```
while (lock) {
   CN.invokeAndBlock(() -> Util.sleep(500));
}
```

I quoted a code like that here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3192

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaSE has some pretty cool features to do that but we don't support them at this time e.g. `CountDownLatch`.

But this is still pretty easy to do:

```
public class SharedVar<T> {
    private T var;
    public T get() { return var; }
    public synchronized void set(T var) {
       this.var = var;
       notifyAll();
    }
    public synchronized T waitForChange() {
       wait();
       return var;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add a few more explanations? What are in your example `notifyAll()` and `wait()`?

Comment: They're methods from the `Object` class. `wait()` stops the current thread in synchronized context and `notifyAll()` wakes up all waiting threads that are sleeping on a given lock. Since both use the same lock ( `this` ) it works.